# Can I take a gas canister on the MS Sarfaq Ittuk ferry?

Tags: ferries, greenland

I plan to travel on the MS Sarfaq Ittuk ferry operated by Arctic Umiaq Line.  I intend to bring a 450g Primus gas canister, as my destination is quite small and might not sell any (they are [for sale in Narsarsuaq](https://blueiceexplorer.gl/equipment/)). Are there any restrictions on bringing gas canisters onboard the MS Sarfaq Ittuk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no mention of any prohibited items on the Arctic Umiaq Line (AUL) [website](https://aul.gl/en/aboard/faq/). Even weapons are permitted, they just need to be handed over to the crew!

I took a similar gas cartridge last summer on a ferry from France to the UK and back. Didn't have any problems.

Since the AUL provides essential transport for otherwise unreachable communities, I doubt they would have any problems with a camping gas cartridge.